# What's causing pMoniker->BindToObject to return 800703E6 (Invalid access to memory location)?

Tags: c#, c++, com, capture, directshow.net

I'm running into a strange problem. I have some code to enumerate Video Input devices, choose one, then get the IBaseFilter for it so I can use it. The original code was a mix of C# and C++, with the DirectShow code in a C++ DLL. This code has worked perfectly fine for a few years. Recently, I decided to update the code to 64-bit and started running into problems.  The C# code uses DirectShow.NET, and is a direct analogue to the original C++ code. Both sets of code have the same problem. C# code is below.

In InitCaptureDevice(), the call to FindCaptureDevice() returns a valid device. I'm searching for a device with a particular name in this case. When I hit the BindToObject() call, I get an "BadImageFormatException, Invalid access to memory location (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)". This happens most of the time, but occasionally, the call succeeds.

To narrow down the problem, I wrote a simple C++ app, not DLLs or C#, that does the same thing, and built for 64-bit. This works correctly every time. I'm stumped. I can't figure out why the C++ only code works, but the C#/C++ mix or the pure C# code gets an exception. Everything is correctly compiled for 64-bit execution. The camera has 64-bit drivers, as evidenced by the fact that the C++ only app works, and I also verified this using Process Explorer.

Can anyone think of anything I might be missing or doing wrong?

```
public static DsDevice FindCaptureDevice( string deviceNameToFind )
{
  DsDevice[] capDevices;

  capDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat( FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice );

  if ( capDevices.Length == 0 )
    throw new Exception( "No DirectShow video input drivers were found." );

  // we found 1 or more devices -- scan the list for the one we want
  if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( deviceNameToFind ))
    return null;

  for ( int i = 0; i < capDevices.Length; i++ )
  {
    // found specified device? 
    if ( capDevices[i].Name.Contains( deviceNameToFind ))
    {
        string monikerDisplayName = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            capDevices[i].Mon.GetDisplayName( null, null, out monikerDisplayName );
            return( capDevices[i] );
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        // skip further searching since caller is looking for a specific device
        break;
    }
  }
  return( null );
}

InitCaptureDevice()
{
  DsDevice captureDev = null;

  try
  {
    captureDev = FindCaptureDevice( deviceName );
  }
  catch
  {
    captureDev = null;
  }
  if ( captureDev == null )
    return false;

  // Bind Moniker to a filter object
  Guid iid = typeof( IBaseFilter ).GUID;
  object source;
  captureDev.Mon.BindToObject( null, null, ref iid, out source );
  IBaseFilter devFilter = (IBaseFilter) source;
}
```

Comment: BadImageFormatException and ERROR_NO_ACCESS are a very strange pair.  I'd trust the first one and assume that ERROR_NO_ACCESS was the mangled outcome when the CLR asked for a more specific error message through IErrorInfo.  You get BadImageFormatException when there's a bitness problem, like a 64-bit app trying to load a 32-bit DLL.  Which certainly fits what you are attempting to do.  You'll see more with SysInternals' Process Monitor, it shows what DLL is getting loaded.

Comment: Hans, yes, I thought it might be a bitness problem, too, but I did a number of different checks.  Process Explorer shows everything is 64-bit. Process Monitor shows that the last DLL being loaded is the DirectShow filter driver for the camera, but the DLL is definitely 64-bit. In the pure C++ app that works, the exact same DLL is getting loaded, and works.

Comment: Could the problem be related to dependent module? For instance, the driver in question is statically linked to FFmpeg (x64), and your application has Win32 version of the same DLL in its directory and it's taken first before doing path search and locate the proper one.

Comment: Thanks, Hans and Roman. I finally found some other cameras with 64-bit drivers to test, and they work fine, so it looks like a problem with the original camera's drivers. I was thrown off by the fact that it works with the C++ only app, but not with the .NET or .NET/C++ apps.